# Position button to dynamic TableView bottom

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, tableview

I have a dynamic TableView that changes size based on API content. That is working fine, but I can't get a button or any content below, outside of the TableView to position correctly and keep the space consistent. The button moves up and down depending on the number of rows in the TableView.

I have a Top Space to TableView constraint set, but it doesn't give me the same amount of space between the bottom of the TableView and the button if my data is longer.

Is there any way to anchor that to bottom of the TableView regardless of if the heading has 1 or 2 lines, etc?

Thanks for any help

[image]

Comment: This means that if there is a long heading for many cells  the button may be bottom below out  of screen ???

Comment: I'm truncating them so they don't get too long. But like in the photo with a 2 line heading the button is up higher.

Comment: Did you give the table a static height in IB

Comment: I'm giving it an estimated hight of 150. And an automatic Row Height. I have a 208 height set on the view in IB. I'm also doing this after I get the data self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.notesTable.contentSize.height

Comment: then make button top = self.notesTable.contentSize.height + tabletopSpace

Comment: I've tried making an align Top to Table constraint but what would the tableTopSpace value be?

Comment: it's top space above table

Comment: I've added a constraint from the button to the top of the tableview and then added some padding. But I get the same result self.buttonFromTableTopConstraint.constant = self.notesTable.contentSize.height + 20

Comment: and what that result ?

Comment: like the above picture, the button doesn't stay at 20 from the table view, it moves like before.

Comment: and off course there is rows below ??????

Comment: the problem is self.notesTable.contentSize.height  value for the visible cell only not all cells summed

Comment: I'm limiting the rows to no more than 3 for this particular page.

Comment: see my answer .......

Comment: Trying to get the last cell height like you said.

Answer (score 1):

1- set tableView height constraint to 3000 (any high number)

2- get bounds of the last cell and access it's y , height from `bounds` property

```
let currentHeight  =  y of last cell  + it's height
```

3- set it to table

```
self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = currentHeight
```

4- hook button's top to tableView's bottom + 20

Answer (score 0):

This is how ended up doing it.

After successfully getting the data.

```
            // Get visible cells and sum up their heights
            let cells = self.notesTable.visibleCells
            var heightOfTableView = 0
            for cell in cells {
                heightOfTableView += Int(cell.frame.height)
            }
            //total tableview height after data loaded
            //so rows aren't cut off or blank
            self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(heightOfTableView)
            //distance from top of TableView to place button
            self.buttonFromTableTopConstraint.constant = CGFloat(heightOfTableView)
```